# JavaScript on Website can't "select" element

Tags: javascript, html, json

i recently started *reworking* my website, mainly adding features or rewriting code. Now, I wanted to add a socials-page (*with my social-media links*) and i want my JavaScript to import the *cards* from a JSON-document. For that, i need to *select* the `socialsTitle`, `socialsLink`, `socialsLinkDisplay` and `socialsIcon`-elements to put in their values. For *selecting* those elements. I did this, but the only element that's just returning `null` is the `socialsLink`.

JS:

```js
const socialsTitle = socialsCard.querySelector("[socialsTitle]");
const socialsLink = socialsCard.querySelector("[socialsLink]");
const socialsLinkDisplay = socialsCard.querySelector("[socialsLinkDisplay]");
const socialsIcon = socialsCard.querySelector("[socialsIcon]");
```

HTML:

```html
<template socialsTemplate>
    <a target="_blank" class="card socialsElement" socialsLink>
        <img alt="" class="appIcon socialsElement" socialsIcon />
        <h1 class="appDetails socialsElement">
            <p class="appName socialsElement" socialsTitle></p>
            <p class="appLink socialsElement" socialsLinkDisplay></p>
        </h1>
    </a>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `socialsCard` is the element having `socialsLink` attribute. `querySelector` is for looking up children nodes within the element you call it on.

Comment: What do I need to change then?

Comment: *querySelector is for looking up **children** nodes* <-- `querySelector()` is for finding matching **descendant** nodes.

Comment: But how do I need to rewrite my code then?

Comment: Can you get a handle to element marked with `socialsTemplate`? If so, you would be able to do: `template.querySelector("[socialsLink]");`

Comment: What exactly do you mean?

Comment: To get element marked with `socialLink` you have to use `querySelector` on the element surrounding it (a parent in DOM tree). In this case, it is `<template socialsTemplate>` so you need to get reference to that element first.